# Where do I find the options for changing the look of the title bar in Android-Studio? (Text color, text alignment, etc)

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, kotlin, layout

The design tab under main_activity in Android Studio doesn't show the top title bar in the preview. I'm trying to realign and change the color of the text in the top title bar but I can't figure out where to find it's settings.

I am able to change the color of the top bar in colors.xml, but I can't find the text settings.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the text appearing in the title bar (formally known as the [Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) or App Bar), you need to alter the `android:label` attribute of the relevant activity entry in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The following example illustrates how this can be done for an `Activity` entitled `MainActivity`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="The text that you'd like to appear in the title bar"
    />
```

I sincerely hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Toolbar inside an AppBarLayout that utilizes Styles to control the color and other characteristics of Toolbar. You have to tweak the styles file as per your individual needs.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```